# View multiple files in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, interface

I just realised that Office 2007 now shows multiple pages per default. I can finally take advantage of that huge monitor I've bought.

Is there a similar feature with Visual Studio?

Something like "View -> Two Pages"

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can use "Tab Groups". Visual Studio supports both horizontal and vertical panes (since at least Visual Studio .NET 2002 I believe, I haven't used VS 5 or 6 in ages..)

There are several ways to create a tab group. One way is:

- Open two files.
- Grab the tab of one of the files and pull it down and slightly to the side
- You'll get a menu prompting you if you want to put it in a new horizontal or vertical pane.
- You can move files between panes by grabbing the tab of the open file and pulling it next to the tabs in the pane you want it in.

Another way is:

- Click Window
- Click New Vertical Tab Group

[Here](http://www.kevinwilliampang.com/post/Visual-Studio-Split-Views.aspx) is a website demonstrating this with pictures and it even includes showing you how to split pane with the **same** file. Handy when refactoring!

Answer (score 7):

Try This:
Click Window -> New Vertical Tab Group

Answer (score 1):

Use Window->New Vertical Tab Group (Visual Studio 2005)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles here looking for how to do it in "Visual Studio Code", I am using version 1.66 and found

View -> Editor Layout -> Split Right

among other options.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

Use View->Document Groups->Two Columns (Visual Studio for Mac 2022)